# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app' while making migrations

Tags: python, django

I was trying to make migrations in Django by these commands,

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I have already saved my_app in installed apps[] of settings.py in my project.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrPIc.png)

Answer (score 3):

You should have your app config setup in `./my_app/apps.py` with this format:

```py
# /my_app/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'
```

And then add call that config class it to the list of installed apps in `Settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # --------------------------
    'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added your app in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. After that try to run above command.